# Fail to decode JSON response if it contains more than x-number of elements

Tags: ios, json, swift

I can successfully decode JSON from this URL, mostly. The query item `-nbd` is the number of "dates" to request.

https://ssp.imcce.fr/webservices/miriade/api/ephemcc.php?-step=1m&-tcoor=3&-teph=1&-observer=43.078148,-79.075699,180.0&-mime=json&-nbd=1440&-output=--iso&-ep=2021-1-17T00:00&-name=p:Sun

When I request `-nbd=769` or fewer dates, `ephem` is correctly decoded every time.

However, when I request `-nbd=770` or more dates, my `dataTask` prints out the entire response with 1440 elements, but `ephem` is `nil`.

What could be going wrong with this?

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let data = data {
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(str)
        
        let ephem = try? decoder.decode(EphemCC.self, from: data)
        completion(ephem)
    } else {
        print("Either no data was returned, or data was not properly decoded.")
        completion(nil)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Sample JSON response:

```
{
  "sso": {
    "num": "11",
    "name": "Sun",
    "type": "planet",
    "parameters": {
      "diameter": 0.1392E+7
    }
  },
  "coosys": {
    "epoch": "J2000",
    "equinox": "J2000",
    "system": "eq_ICRF"
  },
  "ephemeris": {
    "time_scale": "UTC",
    "planetary_theory": "INPOP19A",
    "coordinates": "local",
    "reference_frame": {
      "type": "astrometric J2000",
      "plane": "equator",
      "center": "topocenter",
      "topocenter": {
        "iau_code": "--1",
        "name": "userLocation",
        "longitude": -0.79075698999999986E+2,
        "latitude": 0.43078147999999999E+2,
        "altitude": 0.18E+3
      }
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "Date": "2021-01-17T00:00:00.000",
      "LAST": "02:30:14.28",
      "Az": 0.26002683458818331E+3,
      "H": -0.20245586021541037E+2,
      "Dobs": 0.98378058040177629E+0,
      "VMag": -0.26775508772817108E+2,
      "R": -0.999E+3,
      "RV": 0.42476667062773499E+0
    },

//
// ... etc, 1440 "data" elements received
// 

    {
      "Date": "2021-01-17T23:59:00.000",
      "LAST": "02:33:10.66",
      "Az": 0.25997789921032143E+3,
      "H": -0.19879751688585404E+2,
      "Dobs": 0.98384649280603065E+0,
      "VMag": -0.26775363291013889E+2,
      "R": -0.999E+3,
      "RV": 0.43266153050417039E+0
    }
  ],
  "datacol": {
    "Date": "Date",
    "LAST": "Local sidereal time",
    "Az": "Azimuth",
    "H": "Elevation",
    "Dobs": "Range of target center to observer",
    "VMag": "Apparent magnitude",
    "R": "Atmospheric refraction",
    "RV": "Radial velocity of target wrt observer"
  },
  "unit": {
    "diameter": "km",
    "topocenter": {
      "longitude": "deg",
      "latitude": "deg",
      "altitude": "m"
    },
    "LAST": "hms",
    "Az": "deg",
    "H": "deg",
    "Dobs": "au",
    "VMag": "mag",
    "R": "arcsec",
    "RV": "km/s"
  }
}
```

Comment: `try?` means "If there was an error thrown? I don't care. It might give me infos on why it failed? I don't care". So use a `do { try... } catch { print("Error when trying to ...: \(error)" }` and tell us what's the error. Then with the error, we might need code of `EphemCC` and soem sub codable struct.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for pointing me in this direction. Now I see I had mismatched data types, trying to put Double values into an Int.

Comment: Pure coincidence which element had the data type which wouldn't fit into my malformed struct. Don't ignore the errors, lesson learned.